# How to ignore "--" but not "-"

Tags: java, regex, delimiter

I am using the `useDelimiter` method in Java to ignore all non-letters except for `-`. This is because `-` is used to bind up words like `"three-legged"`. The problem is that `--` occurs several times in the text before and after words. So I want to ignore all occurrences of `--`, but not `-`

This is what my regex pattern looks like so far: `useDelimiter("[[^a-zA-Z&&[^'-]&&\\s]+");`

**EDIT: SOLVED IT! This is what I did:** 
`useDelimiter("[[^a-zA-Z&&[^'&&[^-{1}]]]\\s]+");` - Any improvements to this regex would be gladly appreciated.

**DOUBLE EDIT - I DIDN'T SOLVE IT. BUT JERRY DID LOOK AT HIS RESPONSE FOR CORRECT ANSWER**

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do with your regex. Could you show us some input and expected output? Also include how you are using your scanner.

Comment: Hello, I solved it, but this is the expected input and output: 
Input: "A three-legged horse -- That's what I want"
Print out all words: A three-legged horse that's what I want. So "three-legged" horse is counted as one word because "-" is not ignored, while "--" is ignored and not counted.

Comment: So I takee  it with `-{1}`, quantifiers can be used in Java classes, interresting. I still don't understand the multiple intersections.

Comment: @SingSandibar Updated my answer with a simpler regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your regex is a bit weird. There's no intersection required per se (after fixing the missing `]`):

```
[[^a-zA-Z]&&[^'-]&&\\s]
```

Intersection of `[^a-zA-Z]` and `[^'-]` is the same as `[^a-zA-Z'-]` and intersection of this with `\\s` gives only `\\s`.

Maybe you mean something like:

```
useDelimiter("[^a-zA-Z'-[\\s]]+");
```

And then, you can add the `--` using an alternation and a non-capture group, if I build on your regex:

```
useDelimiter("(?:[^a-zA-Z'-[\\s]]|--)+");
```

Example string:

```
Hello! World! Seems that... -- Hey! That's my three-legged table!
```

Will be split to:

```
Hello
World
Seems
that
Hey
That's
my
three-legged
table
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/rFzItX)

EDIT: A modification of your current regex might be:

```
(?:[[^a-zA-Z&&[^'&&[^-]]]\\s]|--)+
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the comment. I tried to improve my regex, and this is my new edit of the last edit:
useDelimiter("[[^a-zA-Z'&&[^-{1}]]\\s]+");

Is this good, or maybe it can be reduced some more?

Comment: @SingSandibar I'm not sure, because it doesn't seem to be ignoring `--` for me. I removed the `{1}` in the regex and it works the same. Maybe try the last regex?

Comment: I've never heard of quantifier context in Java classes. I wonder if this is true, and/or just at the beginning of sub classes and/or if this could ever be a feature, or does it just do `[-\{\1\}]`

Comment: @sln I get the feeling that it's equating to the literal characters `{1}` though, since removing them didn't appear to cause any change to the behaviour of the function.

Comment: Thank you so much Jerry! Your regex worked! I would just like to know why you had to put the -- after the or (|). Is there a reason for this? I am just asking because I am quite new at regexes...

Comment: @SingSandibar The first part of the regex `[^a-zA-Z'-[\\s]]` makes sure that `-` (among other things) is not matched. If character classes could have definite quantifies, this would have worked: `[^a-zA-Z'-[\\s-{2}]]` but unfortunately, it is not possible to do that, so you have to put it outside with `|`. It's a bit difficult to explain though, but I can try again if it's still not so clear :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Java expert but isin't there a problem with your regex.

```
 [  <-- Unbalanced  '['
 [^a-zA-Z&&[^'-]&&\s]+
```

Comment: Actually, as you can see here, this is valid: http://regex101.com/r/kH6hI4 (but it doesnt do what the author wants it to do regardless)

Comment: @Lindrian - The regex is valid in non-Java engines, it parses as `/[[^a-zA-Z&&[^'-] && \s ]+/x`. Java uses recursion (ie: balanced text) for its bracketing and `&&` keywords.

Comment: In otherwords `[[^a-zA-Z&&[^'-]` is the only class in non-Java.

Comment: Where the non-Java meaning is `[\[\^a-zA-Z\&\&\[\^\'-]`